# Why does MSBuild only work properly in the developer command prompt?

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I'm building a project locally using `msbuild.exe` like:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe MyProject.csproj
```

When I execute it through the **Developer Command Prompt**, everything works as expected.

However, when I execute it through the standard **Command Prompt**, I get an error saying:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.

If I look up that folder path, I can indeed verify it's **invalid** (I only have VS 2015 installed on the machine).

So why isn't it working in **Command Prompt**, or conversely: why *is* it working in **Developer Command Prompt**?

**Edit:** The **.csproj** file is pretty much the Visual Studio 2015 default for an ASP.NET 4 website, and it specifies:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

To me it seems it would default to **10.0** if `VisualStudioVersion` isn't set, but judging from the error message it's assuming VS version **12.0**.

I realize I could just modify the **.csproj** file, replacing **12** with **14**, but I'd rather not go for a workaround, but instead understand why it's working in the **Developer Command Prompt**, but not the standard one.

I'm guessing it potentially has to do with different environment variables, or something along those lines?

Comment: You'll just have much better odds of using the correct MSBuild version.  Which is not the one you tried to use, it is retained only for compat reasons.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant! The build script resolves the MSBuild path from the registry, since I'd like to avoid absolute paths in the script, and that's the path I found. Which one _should_ I use? And is there a way to get its path from an environment variable or similar?

Comment: Type "where msbuild.exe" and it will tell you.  It is not terribly clear why you don't want to use DCP and substitute it with something else.  Whatever you'll conjure up will likely just stop working for the next release.

Comment: That outputs 2 paths when executed through Developer Command Prompt, one being the path I used. However, the _other_ one (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe) works just fine in the standard command prompt! Now I'll just have to figure out a way of finding that path somewhere without having to hard code it into the build script. :) Thanks again! Much appreciated!

Comment: @HansPassant I should probably clarify that I'm working on a PS script (which executes msbuild.exe) for AppVeyor, so the DCP isn't really applicable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run **Developer Command Prompt** you basically run VsDevCmd.bat from VisualStudio's Tools folder and sets some environment variables for the Console that you will be working with. Without those msbuild can't find correct file.

For example it sets VisualStudioVersion environment variable

```
@rem VisualStudioVersion
@rem -------------------
@set VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

It depends on the .csproj but I suspect you might have something similar in it

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

So if the $(VisualStudioVersion) is not defined (and it won't in standard **Command Prompt**) it will use the version 12. And when you run it through **Developer Command Prompt** this gets set to 14 and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help Pawel! However, I have **10.0** in my `.csproj` file, which threw me off a bit. :/ Either way, I'll accept your answer as it's also helpful, and I can't accept Hans' comments as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant pointed me in the right direction in the comments, and typing `where msbuild.exe` in the **Developer Command Prompt** showed that it had *two* paths to MSBuild:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

The first one works in *both* the standard **Command Prompt**, and the **Developer Command Prompt**.

The second one (which my build script had retrieved from the registry) only works in **Developer Command Prompt**, probably explained by what Pawel said in his answer (essentially due to missing/different environment variables).

In my build script, I changed the registry path from...

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0\`

to...

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0\`

...and that produces the proper (current) MSBuild path in the build script.